# How to Troubleshoot a "Greyed Out" Printer

Tags: printer

We have a Window 10 Pro 64bit workstation sharing a label printer with other workstations.

When you "Add a printer" this label printer is listed and installation is "successful", however, when you view the printer at "Devices and Printers", the printer's Icon is 70% opacity (some might say it is "greyed out").

[image]

When you attempt printing a label, it just sits in the queue and never prints.

We have multiple workstations successfully consuming this shared label printer. All systems are Windows 10 64bit. However, this one particular workstation always shows the printer "greyed out". I can't figure out why. The installation process has been the same for all workstations consuming this printer, but even after numerous re-installs, this particular workstation cannot print to it.

The built-in trouble shooter is useless. The only feedback I have is an icon that is partial opacity.

How can I discover what's causing this issue?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Print Spooler service?

Comment: If you click on the printer icon, do you get the "Open queue", "Manage", and "Remove device" buttons?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, on both computers: 1) The computer sharing the label printer, 2) and the computer attempting to consume the printer via the share.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - When I double-click I see an empty print queue. When I right-click I see [this](https://i.imgur.com/sg6fMa7.png).

Comment: @LonnieBest I actually meant an ordinary single-click, but never mind. Is the printer set to offline or is the print queue paused? Just to make sure.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It says on the title bar of the print-queue window [Use Printer Offline](https://i.imgur.com/pSDqiqr.png). The printer is on, though, and other workstations are printing to it via the share frequently.

Comment: @LonnieBest From Microsoft: Select Start > Settings (Gear-shaped Settings icon) > Devices > Printers & scanners. Then select your printer > Open queue. Under Printer, make sure "Use Printer Offline" is not selected.

Comment: @LonnieBest In the same menu as "Use Printer Offline", there is probably an optiuon "Resume Printing" or perhaps "Pause Printing". (The greyed-out icon *might* mean the printer is offline, but I don't have a printer on the computer I'm using at the moment to investigate further.)

Comment: @LonnieBest Also, were any registry patches applied to this particular machine to address the [Windows Print Spooler PrintNightmare vulnerability](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-fixes-windows-print-spooler-printnightmare-vulnerability/)?

Comment: I do the following in this situation.  First, delete the print queue  ...      net stop spooler  ;   del %systemroot%\System32\spool\printers\* /Q ;  
Type net start spooler .... Second, uninstall the printer (programs and features) and delete any instance in Devices and Printers.    Now restart the computer and add this printer from Devices and Printers.  This works better in a number of cases than the printer install package.

Comment: @AndrewMorton [Make sure "Use Printer Offline" is not selected](https://i.imgur.com/bElOJbv.png)? I see no such option where you described.

Comment: @LonnieBest Well that's strange, considering the title of that window. If the UI doesn't present the option, perhaps you can get something useful from [PowerShell Core Setting A Printer Online](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61024516/1115360). (N.B. The image shows something that you blanked out in the question.)